# Template arguments for class object

Tags: c++, class, templates

My class looks as follows:

```
template <typename Function, class RNG>
class Langevin{
public:
       Langevin(RNG & gen_, Function & func_,vector & qp_)
       : gen(gen_),force(func_),qp(qp_){}
...
private:
RNG & gen;
Function & func;
vector & qp;
};
```

now i want to instantiate an object of class, which template arguments do i have to give over? When RNG is the random-engine-type and Function is the type of the lambda-function.

```
auto h_force=[](double q, const double k){return -k*q;};
std::default_random_engine gen(314);
```

i think it should look like:

```
Langevin<auto, std::default_random_engine> object(gen,h_force,qp);
```

I don't unterstand what i should write instead of `auto` maybe something like `std::function`   respectively i am not sure if i  do it correctly.

Comment: `decltype` should help

Comment: You should pass `decltype(h_force)`.

Comment: I think i should declare the private variables as follows:
 `RNG & gen;
Function & force; `
But still i get an error message:
 `‘Langevin<main()::<lambda(double, double)>, std::linear_congruential_engine<long unsigned int, 16807ul, 0ul, 2147483647ul> >::force’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
 Function & force;
 `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every lambda expression produces a closure with an unique anonymous type. You can get the type of the closure by using `decltype`:

```
Langevin<decltype(h_force), std::default_random_engine> object(gen,h_force,qp);
```

---

In C++17, it should be enough to write:

```
Langevin object(gen,h_force,qp);
```

...thanks to [*class template argument deduction*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).